# how to show ubercart fields in manage fields section of content type

Tags: ubercart, entities

I'm needing to access the price, sku, etc fields in the manage fields section in structure/contenttypes. None of these fields show up in the manage fields section? I can manage their display under manage display tab, but I need to be able to manage the field itself in order for conditional fields to affect them.

How can I show these fields in the manage fields section?

Thanks in advance.

Billy

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to create a relationship between the content node and the product node. In the content node, you will only see a reference field pointing to the product node, which usually holds all the constructs you are looking for.